# Reading blob data from Oracle database using C#

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-core, blob

I need to read blob data from Oracle database and save it in a directory. I successfully convert blob data to byte array (`byte[]`) and I save it with
`File.WriteAllBytes()` method. When I want to open the output (for example It's a pdf file), It cannot be open. Even the file size is around 3 MB, but it won't open for some reason that I'm looking for.

My sample code:

```
using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString)) {
    connection.Open();
    using (OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand()) {
        command.CommandText = "my query ...";
        using (OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
            if (reader.Read()) {
                byte[] buffer = reader.GetOracleBlob(reader.GetOrdinal("blobField")).Value;
                File.WriteAllBytes("D:\\test1.pdf", buffer);
                return blobData;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PS: My project is asp.net core web API/

I tried doing this with `OracleConnection` and `EFCore`, but the result was the same. The file did not open.

I'm expecting to save the blob file from Oracle database into a directory and the file should be OK (can be opened).

Comment: First of all, are you *sure* the binary data represents a pdf file? Second, you should verify that roundtripping some data to the DB works. I.e. generate some random data, write it to the DB, read it, check that the result is identical. That should help eliminate the database as a potential source of errors.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with a **minimal** example of the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data (which you have checked generates a valid document in the database); a **complete** example of your code that we can execute (i.e. not `"my query ..."`); details of the problem ("the file did not open" is a symptom, it does not tell us what is wrong with the file). Help us to help you and provide us with a complete problem and details of **YOUR** efforts to debug the problem.

Comment: Firstly, could you open the file before it was inserted into the database? If not then the file is corrupt and you could never open it. Secondly, use something else to download the blob from the database (i.e. SQL Developer) and see if you can open the file when you download it from that; if you cannot then the problem is with the data and (possibly) not with your code. Thirdly, do a byte-by-byte comparison of the file inserted into the database and the file downloaded from the database and see if they are the same; if not then you need to debug your code.

Comment: May be It is encoded in base64? Look at the downloaded file if it ends by "=="  or "=" at the end of file? When I look at the some pdf it started with "%PDF-1.5" where 1.5 is version. If there is only sequence of ASCII charachters with "=" or "==" it is encoded in base64.